# Why the functionality of swap-token and dispatch is disabled in parity-bridges?

Tags: xcm, parity-bridges-common

I was working with parity-bridges-common from the parity but i'm facing issues during the transfer of native tokens and i'm not able to send a custom message to the relay chain from solo-chain.

Can anyone please guide me through this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swap-token and dispatch functionality of the Parity Bridges project was disabled because they were not deemed necessary or actively being used by users. The developers of the project decided to focus on improving other aspects of the project that were more important and relevant to the needs of users.

Additionally, the swap-token and dispatch functionality involved security risks and required significant resources to maintain, which further contributed to the decision to disable them.

However, it is worth noting that the Parity Bridges project is open source, so anyone can fork the project and implement the swap-token and dispatch functionality if they wish to do so.